# How to keep contents in a root site by doing the site swap?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site, root

I did the Invoke-SPOSiteSwap for SharePoint on PowerShell. While I was able to successfully do it, the contents of the root site went in to the archiveURl specified. Is there a way to prevent that and keep the contents in the root site?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Site Swap feature replaces the entire site. You would need to use a 3rd party migration tool to copy over the content or if it is just documents, you can use the Move/Copy feature built into the SharePoint UI.

Comment: Ok-so I can just rebuild/create the subsites on the new site and move over the items from archive to there? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can. I should note that subsites are not recommended in SPO, but rather move to the Hub Site model.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying why? I understand with hub-sites you can connect to other sites. However my organization leans a lot on clean cut URLs like /department and want to stray away from /sites/department.

Comment: I'll link you to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites. Read through it but that explains why Hub sites are better (isolating units of work, ease of governance, among others).